# How I can to put page not found On case invalid slug

Tags: reactjs

I need to put page notfound if slug invalid.
I have these routes

```
<Switch>
    
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug' component = { Home } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug/register' component = { Signup } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug/event' component = { Event } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug/contact' component = { Contact } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug/login' component = { Login } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/:slug/show-details' component = { ShowList } />
    <Route  exact path = '/myflix/*' component = { NotFound } />

  </Switch>
```

:slug get from API I have some slug in API I need to put error when slug invalid
how I can do this? On case invalid slug

```
const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <div>NotFound</div>
  )
}
export default NotFound
```

Comment: The router doesn't know which slugs are valid, one option is just to redirect to your error page when a request fails (or, when you detect an invalid slug, however that happens in your system)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Error } from './Pages'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes> 
          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />  
        </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[from a comment]:

```
import { Home, Error } from './Pages' 
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom"; 

function App() { 
    return ( <> <BrowserRouter> <Routes> {
            !localStorage.token ? <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} /> 
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />} /> 
        </Routes> </BrowserRouter> </> );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I do this in index.js

Comment: <Suspense fallback="loading">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Suspense >,

Comment: ```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const Loading = <div className='bg-black'> Looading</div>
ReactDOM.render(<Suspense fallback={Loading}> <App /></Suspense>, document.getElementById('root')); 

in index.js file

Comment: I do this in index.js ==> NO

in App.jsx

Comment: this is my app.jx  <div className="App">
        <Router />
      </div>

Comment: App.jsx
`
import { Home,  Error   } from './Pages'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {

  return (
    <> 
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {!localStorage.token ?
            <>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} /> 
              <Route path="*" element={<Error />} /> 
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;

`